# Passar valor para 2 caminhos diferentes

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, codeigniter, funções

Gostaria de passar a variável  **var data = 'codreq=' + id;** para dois caminhos. Isso é possível? Se sim, alguém pode me ensinar.
Consigo apenas passar para este caminho:

```
url: "<?= base_url('coordenador/protocolo/buscaDetalhesRequerimento') ?>"
```

Preciso passar para este ao mesmo tempo:

```
url: "<?= base_url('coordenador/protocolo/responder_requerimento') ?>"



<script>
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("a#visualizar").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var data = 'codreq=' + id;
        //alert(data);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?= base_url('coordenador/protocolo/buscaDetalhesRequerimento') ?>",
            data: data,
            success: function (text) {
                //if (text === "success") {
                $(".dados").html(text);
                //  });
                //window.location.reload(true);
                //}
            }
        });


    });
});
```

Comment: Porque não cria uma função e coloca esse código AJAX dentro dela e depois chama ela duas vezes passando a URL de destino apropriada como parâmetro?

Comment: Tô tentando fazer assim, mais o codeigniter tá foda, tô me batendo!

Comment: O que aparece no console.log quando tu chama função `$("a#visualizar").click()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enviando o mesmo dado para dois ou mais *requests* simultâneos no mesmo *click*:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#visualizar").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var url1 = '<?= base_url('coordenador/protocolo/buscaDetalhesRequerimento') ?>';
        var url2 = '<?= base_url('coordenador/protocolo/responder_requerimento') ?>';
        $.when(
            $.post(url1,{codereq:id},function(text) {
                console.log(text);
                $(".dados").html(text);
            }),
            $.post(url2,{codereq:id},function(resp2) {
                console.log(resp2);
            })
        )
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Poxa, ainda não me retornou!

Comment: Não retornou o quê?

Comment: a variavel data aparece teste mas ela nao envia para as urls nem a 1 nem a 2 já com o ajax vai normal, só que eu nao sei fazer para ir para duas urls diferentes

Comment: Você deve estar fazendo algo errado. Isso aqui: `'codreq=' + id;` parece `$_GET`, mas vc está enviando dados via `$_POST`. Pelo `$_POST` o mais adequado seria `var codreq = id;` ou `codereq:id`. Vou editar a resposta, mas preste atenção ao seu código.

Comment: hummm entendi, vou tentar aqui.